# React Native: How to Encrypt Video Files for Playback without Impacting Performance

Tags: javascript, react-native, encryption, video

I have a smart TV box device running on Android 11 that contains video files in MP4 format. I would like to protect these video files by encrypting them and then playing them in a custom video player on my React Native app. I have tried several methods to protect the video files, but they have not been effective.

Due to the large file size of the video files (up to 400 MB), it's not practical to decrypt the entire file into memory. This could result in performance issues and negatively impact the user experience.

Is there a way to encrypt the video files and play them on app without having to decrypt the entire file at once? Ideally, I'm looking for a solution that allows me to decrypt the video file chunk by chunk to avoid performance issues.

this is how I decrypt the video currently

```
async function decrypt(encryptedData) {
  const decipher = await Crypto.createDecipher('aes-128-ecb', encryptionKey);
  let decryptedData = decipher.update(encryptedData, 'hex', 'utf8');
  decryptedData += decipher.final('utf8');
  return decryptedData;
}
```

Comment: You could try converting your MP4 into a **fragmented MP4** where the total duration is broken into separate MP4 chunks of N-seconds . Check your video editor for such option or else use a tool (_eg:_ Handbrake, or FFmpeg, etc) to segment the file. When segmented each piece (MP4 or M4S) is playable as a separate file so you encrypt all pieces but then **only decrypt the chunk that you currently need**...

Comment: @WahidullahShadab, not any concrete solutions nom I ended up encrypting the videos using FFMPEG, but decrypting it is easy with some basic skills

Comment: @Sarkar how is the performance of your app? Do you have any bench marks of your app?